# Getting syntax error while email attachment

Tags: asp.net, email, email-attachments

I am trying to attach excel file using file upload but getting syntax error.

I have tried every possibility, but could not solve it.

Any help'll be appreciated.

Getting Error is-

```
the best overloaded method match for 'system.collections.objectmodel.collection
<system.net.mail.attachment>.Add(System.Net.Mail.Attachment)' has some invalid arguments
```

My Code is-

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
    msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
    msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
   if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        String FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
       // MailAttachment mailAttachment = new MailAttachment(FileName, MailEncoding.Base64);
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment mailAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, 
                                       FileName);
        msg.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);
    }

    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtFrom.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two namespaces that allow sending mails in the .NET framework: [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [System.Web.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Both contain similar classes. I suspect that there is a reference to System.Web.Mail in the `using` directives at the top of your file.

You create the MailMessage object by using the fully qualified name `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`. For the `MailAttachment` on the other hand you do not qualify the namespace. In order to make this work, you need to decide which namespace to take. System.Net.Mail provides a SMTP implementation. So I'd recommend to use only the classes from System.Net.Mail:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    String FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment mailAttachment = 
            new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, 
                                           FileName);
// ...
```

Comment: Exception---Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\ExpenseReport (5).xls'.

Comment: @AzharShahid: you need to specify the full path of the file. Check the content of the `FileName` variable.

Comment: @Markus- I am getting file from fileupload control.

Comment: @AzharShahid: I've updated the answer to use the stream of the FileUpload. Hope it helps.

Comment: Changed my code in question too.. getting syntax error

Comment: @AzharShahid: there was one redundant line. I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

`MailAttachment` does not derive from `System.Net.Mail.Attachment`. Use `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` instead:

```
public static void CreateMessageWithAttachment(string server)
{
    // Specify the file to be attached and sent. 
    // This example assumes that a file named Data.xls exists in the 
    // current working directory. 
    string file = "data.xls";
    // Create a message and set up the recipients.
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
       "jane@contoso.com",
       "ben@contoso.com",
       "Quarterly data report.",
       "See the attached spreadsheet.");

    // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
    Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    // Add time stamp information for the file.
    ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
    disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
    disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
    disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
    // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
    message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.mail.attachment